# When JavaScript runs

Tags: javascript, jslink

Working on an overview of all possibilities of adding JavaScript.

**Can someone confirm Custom Actions run **after** JSLinks**

By execution order:

## Page Scripts

using <script> tags or scriptlink includes.

#### MasterPage

The MasterPage executes on every SharePoint page.

- http://thomasdaly.net/2010/12/16/scriptlink-vs-whats-the-difference/

*On Office365/SharePoint Online this method is discouraged by Microsoft (so any Cloud functionalty pushed by Microsoft does not conflict with your code*

#### Page

Same construct as MasterPages, scripts are only loaded on **one** page

Edit ASPX page in SharePoint Designer (or any text editor)

[image]

## JSLink injections on WebParts, Views, Forms, Fields

JSLink connection to CSR JS files (but can be any JS file)

*SharePoint Online allows for absolute URLs, OnPrem requires URLs with `~token`*

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/610259/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1039724/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Forms-p
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a
- http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/5-facts-about-jslink-in-sharepoint-2013-you-might-not-know
- BookMarklet [iCSR Link Manager](https://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html)
  update JSLink settings on WebParts & Views, deploy JS files to Style Library

[image]

## Calculated Column (View)

(Like the CEWP) Executes JavaScript **while the page is loading**

- https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How

[image]

## Custom Actions

- ASPX Page [UserCustomActions](https://github.com/johnnliu/UserCustomActionsConfigPage)
- https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/JavaScript-injection-in-SharePoint-Online-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices
  MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn913116.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

[image]

## WebParts on page

#### CEWP

<script> content

The code is executed while the page is loading, so put the WebPart at the bottom of the page or use jQuery ready function or SharePoints [`_spBodyOnloadFunctionNames`](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/)

*Without content IN the WebPart, the title can link to a JavaScript in a Library*

#### SEWP

[image]

## Browser

These scripts (Great for Admin tasks) are **not** part of SharePoint but can run in the Browser (**for the current Browser/User only**)

#### Extension

Browser Extensions (Chrome & FireFox) must be installed

- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)
  Edit CSR files (and create JSLinks) with Live Updating
- (Chrome Browser Extension) [Chrome SP Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en)
  Edit SharePoint files, add ScriptLinks to SiteCollection/Webs, manage Web Property Bag

**These are powerfull ones, executing script automatically on pages**

- [(Chrome) TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
- [(FireFox) GreaseMonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/)

#### Console (manual)

#### Chrome Snippets (manual)

Allow for editting JavaScript against the current SharePoint context.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en

#### Bookmarklet (manual)

- BookMarklet [iCSR Link Manager](https://icsr.github.io/JSLinkManager.html)
  update JSLink settings on WebParts & Views, deploy JS files to Style Library

J1 J5 JW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually the opposite; I can confirm that custom actions run **before** jslink.  It works out well that this is true.  If you have the same dependency on a number of jslink scripts, you can load it once as a site or web custom action.

The alternative is to set all of your jslink to 
`"~sitecollection/<path>/jquery.js|~sitecollection/<path>/yourscript.js"` which gets pretty messy as dependencies grow.